# How to avoid Lazy fetch, even when it is set to lazy fetch mode and ecrypt/decrypt column.....?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one to many association in my dto,

Parent DTO : **Question**
Child DTO : **History**

**Question 1:**

Means One question record has many history records, I am using JPA2.x with hibernate, 
I bound the entities with lazy fetching method/mode. some places I want the lazy fetching...
and some places I don't want the lazy fetching not even egar. Means I don't want the data collection itself. I need only the parent class list, even if I call getHistories() method, it should not do lazy fetch in few places.... How to use entityManager to avoid lazy fetching.....even though the collection was set to lazy fetch mode.....?

**Question 2:**

I need to encrypt the question using mysql encode/decode functions. when inserting encrypt the value and save. when selecting decode the content.....

Solution can be in mapping or criteria query...?

Thanks In Advance....!

Comment: fetch strategies - please refer to [this link](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies). mysql encode/ decode, you'll have to issue specific HQL queries that invoke these functions. I would instead prefer to encrypt decrypt in Java using say Base64 or some other java implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

Your requirement makes no sense. If you don't want to access the history, don't call `getHistories()`. If you access the collection of History, either your Question is attached, and the collection will be loaded, or it's detached, and you'll get a lazy loading exception.

Question 2:
See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/ColumnTransformer.html. The example in the javadoc is precisely what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, you need to do two things,

1. If you want your parent-child entities to be selected 'lazily', then annotate the bir-directional fields with fetch = lazy. This should work well in the hibernate session, as long as you dont load or 'touch' one of the lazy loaded fields.
2. If you want your parent-child entities to be selected 'eagerly', then anotate the fields in the bi-directional association as fetch = eager.
3. If you want 'some places I don't want the lazy fetching not even egar', then you have to decide at code time, whether to have a relationship between the parent-child entity, if you don't, then just dont map the bi-directional association. You *CAN* create more than one entity class to map different assoications, even entities with no association.